# Easiest way to launch a Jupyter notebook after installing `Nbmake`

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, pytest, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I followed along [Semaphore's Blog Post](https://semaphoreci.com/blog/test-jupyter-notebooks-with-pytest-and-nbmake) on testing Jupyter notebooks using `pytest` and `Nbmake`. This is a great post, and testing worked great. Summarizing how I applied the blog post:

1. run `pip install pytest nbmake` into a virtual env
2. run `pytest --nbmake notebooks` -where `notebooks` is a folder containing my `*.ipynb` files

It's working correctly, because when I add an intentional error cell, the test fails.

What I'd like to know is the minimal set of additional libraries and commands that are necessary for me to be able to *interactively run* my notebooks as well in the same environment. I know that you can also add the `--overwrite` flag to inspect the results, and this is definitely very useful, but that's not what I'm asking for. In particular, I'd like to have steps (3) and (4) which:

3. `pip install some additional libraries` -or maybe we can even skip this step altogether?
4. `awesome-jupyter-command notebooks/foo.ipynb` -so now the jupyter kernel is started and automatically displays `foo.ipynb` for interactive evaluation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most jupyter server commands (.e.g `jupyter notebook` and `jupyter lab`) accept a directory or notebook file as a positional argument, so you can do:

```
pip install jupyterlab
jupyter lab notebooks/foo.ipynb
```

which will launch the server and open the specified file.

Some other examples, for different flavors of UI:

```
# 'retro' single-document interface with new features
pip install retrolab
jupyter retro notebooks/foo.ipynb

# 'classic' application, which is trying to push folks to lab-based UI
pip install notebook
jupyter notebook notebooks/foo.ipynb
```

There's also [nbopen](https://pypi.org/project/nbopen/) which adds an additional step of checking for already-runnning servers, rather than always starting a new one:

```
pip install nbopen
nbopen notebooks/foo.ipynb
```

Comment: Thank @minrk. I tested using `retrolab` and it's really fast, simple and elegant. Great answer!